# pycrypto and Google App Engine on windows 10

Tags: google-app-engine, windows-10, google-app-engine-python

I'm trying to run pycrypto (2.6) on google app engine (1.9.32) with python 2.7 on windows 10.

I've added the following to my app.yaml:

```
libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: "2.6"
```

and added the following config:

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/tmp'
```

But I'm still getting the following error:

> The Python egg cache directory is currently set to:
>
> /tmp
>
> Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory? 
>   You can
>   change the cache directory by setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment
>   variable to point to an accessible directory.

pycrypto works fine on windows 10 in *python command line*. The problem is just in the **Google app engine**.

How is it possible to work around this?

2 side notes:

1. The phenomenon is known as the [Python egg error](https://davidwalsh.name/python-eggs).
2. Windows 10 folder locking in read-only is [documented](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=windows+10+read+only+problem). No solutions seemed to work so far.

Comment: GAE is sandboxed. look here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27 you can't import from outside your project directory.

Comment: I managed to import pycrypto from the GAE libraries.
It was failing on _write permissions_ in the windows files system.

Comment: you should consider answering your own question, if you have a solution